# LNK2019 Error Header is included but not linked?

Tags: c++, linker

I have some classes and headers that are external to my program that i wish to use. I am using MSVC2013 and have specified the location of these files in the "Additional include directories" entry in the project settings window. Intellisense recognises the paths and provides the appropriate syntax highlight and my program compiles fine except at the end it throws LNK2019 errors for any usage of these classes. Is there another place in linker settings I need to specify to link external files or am i missing something obvious here.

Error messages:

```
MainWindow.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __cdecl QPropertyEditorWidget::QPropertyEditorWidget(class QWidget *)" (??0QPropertyEditorWidget@@QEAA@PEAVQWidget@@@Z) referenced in function "public: __cdecl MainWindow::MainWindow(class QWidget *)" (??0MainWindow@@QEAA@PEAVQWidget@@@Z)
```

Answer (score 1):

Header files typically provide the API and/or data structures for some other code (most likely a library). With the headers you know about the "other" code, but you don't actually "have it" in your program.

Specifying where to find the headers is only half of the problem. You also need to specify where to find the object files (or libraries), and which objects or libraries to link against.

Comment: Right. So how do i specify where to find the object files part?

Comment: Don't have MSVC in front of me so I can't tell you for sure. It'll be somewhere in your project/solution settings. It's got a fairly obvious name.

Comment: Well I have been looking through the settings and tried a bunch of different things that stood out to me without much success. If you could point me in the right direction when you do have msvc in front of you I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Sorry - you'll have to google it. I don't have a windows box at the moment.